# Python: How to read a text file containing co-ordinates in row-column format into x-y co-ordinate arrays?

Tags: python, coordinates

I have a text file with numbers stored in the following format:

```
1.2378 4.5645

6.789 9.01234

123.43434 -121.0212
```

... and so on.

I wish to read these values into two arrays, one for x co-ordinates and the other for y co-ordinates. Like, so

```
x[0] = 1.2378

y[0] = 4.5645

x[1] = 6.789

y[1] = 9.01234
```

... and so on.

How should I go about reading the text file and storing values?

Comment: Please show the code you've attempted to read and parse the file with

Comment: FWIW, you may be better off with one list of objects, where those objects have attributes x and y.  Parallel lists are workable, but they tend to cause problems over time.

Comment: it depends on the application, a lot of numerical libraries use parallel lists. For example matplotlib takes seperate lists for the x and y coordinates. It is also more memory efficient if you use a single set of x coordinate for several sets of y coordinates, such as when fitting a model to empirical data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One method:

```
x,y = [], []
for l in f:
    row = l.split()
    x.append(row[0])
    y.append(row[1])
```

where f is the file object (from open() for instance)

You could also use the csv library

```
import csv
with open('filename','r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f,delimeter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        x.append(row[0])
        y.append(row[1])
```

And you can also use zip to make it more succinct (though possibly less readable:

```
x,y = zip(*[l.split() for l in f])
```

where f is the file object, or

```
import csv
x,y = zip(*csv.reader(f,delimeter=' '))
```

again where f is the file object. Not that the last two methods will load the entire file into memory (although if you are using python 3 you can use generator expressions and avoid that).

Comment: Thank you, the first method works! I was able to parse the file perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Read it per lines, and split it using `split`:

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        x, y = line.split()
        #do something meaningful with x and y
```

Or if you don't mind with storing the whole list to your computer's memory:

```
with open('f.txt') as f:
    coordinates = [(c for c in line.split()) for line in f]
```

And if you want to store the `x`s and `y`s in separate variables:

```
xes = []
ys = []
with open('f.txt') as f:
     for line in f:
         x, y = line.split()
         xes.append(x)
         ys.append(y)
```

Comment: I'm new to Python. Will your first method create two separate 1-D arrays containing x and y co-ords respectively?

Comment: The first method just stores x and y into variables, which you would then have to do something with to store them into arrays, the third method does that.

Comment: @user3128217 as Thayne mentioned, the first stores x and y to a temporary variable in the loop. The second stores both in one variable, and the third maps all of them to `x` and `y`.